# How can I add/remove Elements from Jlist_1 to Jlist_2 (Java netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, jlist

[image: Java Jlist Pic]

I want add element to Selected Subject List from Total Subjects List and want remove the element which was add in Selected Subject List from Total Subjects List

I am using netbeans.(Java Application)

Please anybody help to solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

The "Hire/File" demo shows how you can remove an item from the DefaultListModel and how you can add an item to the DefaultListModel.

So you combine the logic of those two events and put the code into the ActionListener of you button and you have your solution.

The main difference in your code is that instead of getting the item to add from the text field you get the "selected item" from the JList.